# run time error 13: type mismatch everytime i run my code

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I get this [type mismatch (Error 13)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) when I try to run the script. Below is the code highlighted error.
I'm trying to enter this formula with VBA into the cell but I got an error.

```
TopVisibleCell.Formula = _
 "=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(I2,SEARCH( " - " ,I2)-1)),I2,LEFT(I2,SEARCH( " - " ,I2)-1))"
```

Comment: I would advice you to break up formula in small pieces and check exactly where you are getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape `"` in VBA with `""`

```
TopVisibleCell.Formula = _ 
"=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(I2,SEARCH("" - "",I2)-1)),I2,LEFT(I2,SEARCH("" - "",I2)-1))"
```

Comment: thanks. its works. this is actually after i filter the columns to get the top visible cell but the the row in column I is not right. the numbers will change everytime i filter. so do you know how to make that to become the row number ?

Comment: Assuming you have Row 1 as the Header Row you could try: `topRow = Range("I2:I" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Row`